# asyncio awaitable object - basic example

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand how to make an awaitable object. The definition from the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) states:

> An object with an __await__ method returning an iterator.

Guided by that definition I wrote the sample code:

```
import asyncio

async def produce_list():
        num = await Customer()
        print(num)

class Customer(object):

    def __await__(self):
        return iter([1, 2, 3, 4])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(produce_list())
```

The flow that I expected was:

1. Event loop gives control to `produce_list()`. `produce_list()` gives up execution on `num = await Customer()`.
2. `Customer()` is executed and returns an iterator. Which because returns the first value in the iterator. ***Q1:*** am not clear here why `num` isn't becoming the iterator itself. Also what is doing a `send` here?
3. Once the last value the iterator has been reached. `num = 4` the execution of the coroutine continues to `print(num)`, and prints the value 4.

What I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/workspace/dashboard/so_question_await.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
---> 18 loop.run_until_complete(produce_list())

/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py in run_until_complete(self, future)
    464             raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
    465 
--> 466         return future.result()
    467 
    468     def stop(self):

/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py in result(self)
    291             self._tb_logger = None
    292         if self._exception is not None:
--> 293             raise self._exception
    294         return self._result
    295 

/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py in _step(***failed resolving arguments***)
    239                 result = coro.send(None)
    240             else:
--> 241                 result = coro.throw(exc)
    242         except StopIteration as exc:
    243             self.set_result(exc.value)

~/workspace/dashboard/so_question_await.py in produce_list()
      5 
      6 async def produce_list():
----> 7         num = await Customer()
      8         print(num)
      9 

RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: 1
```

What concepts have I gotten wrong here?

In the end I'm looking for an example that uses iteration through a list as an event to return to the control of the coroutine.

Answer (score 11):

`__await__` returns an iterator because the underlying mechanism for coroutines is originally based on the `yield from` syntax. In practice, `__await__` returns either `iter(some_future)` or `some_coroutine.__await__()`. It can be used to create objects that produce different values every time they are awaited. See this simple example:

```
import asyncio
import random

class RandomProducer:

    def __await__(self):
        return self.producer().__await__()

    async def producer(self):
        sleep = random.random()
        value = random.randint(0, 9)
        return await asyncio.sleep(sleep, result=value)

async def main():
    producer = RandomProducer()
    while True:
        print(await producer)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

---

To answer your comments:

> Does every coroutine eventually ends up calling `asyncio.sleep`?

No, and `asyncio.sleep` is actually not the end of the chain. At the very bottom, it's always a future that is being yielded: the coroutine chain asks the event loop "please wake me up when this future has a result". In the case of `asyncio.sleep`, it uses `loop.call_later` to set the result of the future after a given amount of time. The loop provides more methods for scheduling callbacks: `loop.call_at`, `loop.add_reader`, `loop.add_writer`, `loop.add_signal_handler`, etc.

> An asyncio library such as aiohttp. I'm assuming there is some code somewhere that doesn't rely on existence of previous coroutines.

All the IO operations have to end up delegating to the event loop in order to achieve single-threaded concurrency.
For instance, aiohttp relies on the [loop.create_connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_connection) coroutine to [manage the TCP connection](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/a05fa9e7f61b6af0170d3a86c9117c5c5baff642/aiohttp/connector.py#L705-L710).

Comment: I'm actually trying to get an example that in the end doesn't call an previously defined asyncio lib method. In the end you're passing the `await asyncio.sleep(sleep, result=value)`. The motivation is to try an understand how would one approach the writing of a new asyncio framework.

Comment: Or perhaps to rephrase it. Does every coroutine eventually ends up calling `asyncio.sleep`?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer `how would one approach the writing of a new asyncio framework.` Do you mean an asyncio library such as [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or an asyncio alternative such as [curio](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio)? Also, see my edit.

Comment: An asyncio library such as aiohttp. I'm assuming there is some code somewhere that doesn't rely on existence of previous coroutines (which was what I was trying to achieve with the `Customer` example.

Comment: It looks like the `coroutine model` mostly bases on the `event loop`. Due to the CPU-intensive actually don't need this kind user space threads. The `coroutine` only has value when come across the I/O tasks.
So can we treat the `await  async_client_request()` to a process: 1. register the TCP socket  `writable` event to the `event loop`, 2. when it is writable, then the `http client` write the content to the socket, and then register the `read` event, 3. when it is   readable, then `future` return, and the code start from the `await` line again

Answer (score 2):

@Vincent's answer is probably what you want, since it will let you use your `__await__` method to call more async code.

However, [a bit of searching through python's implementation of Tasks](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Python-AsyncIO-Awaitable-Coroutine-Future-Task/) shows that the iterators returned by **async** are supposed to either return None (sending control back to the event loop) or else raise an exception whose value is their return.

So, the following works:

```
class MyIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 2

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.n -= 1
        if self.n >= 0:
            return None # yields control to outer loop
        raise StopIteration(12) # "return" value stored in exc.value

class MyTask:
    def __await__(self):
        return MyIter()

async def test():
    ans = await MyTask()
    print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole asyncio is built with sequential tasks iteration. You can create custom iterator/generator, with `__await__` method, or you can make coroutine by the old-fasioned-way:

```py
import types, asyncio


@types.coroutine
def arange(start):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(start):
        numbers.append(i)
        yield  # always should be None
    return numbers


async def main():
    return await arange(10)


print(asyncio.run(main()))
```

If you want to make asynchronous generator, please, read [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/).

To better understand, you can imagine asyncio event_loop as a deque of running generators, here is a simple example:

```py
from collections import deque


def arange(stop):
    for i in range(1, stop + 1, 1):
        print(i, "/", stop)
        yield
    else:
        return i


def gather(*tasks):
    return_values = {task: None for task in tasks}
    events = deque(tasks)

    while events:
        try:
            task = events.pop()
            next(task)
            events.appendleft(task)
        except StopIteration as exc:
            return_values[task] = exc.value

    return tuple(return_values.values())


result1, result2 = gather(arange(3), arange(5))
print(result1, result2)
```

The result is the same as you declare `arange` with `types.coroutine` and call these awaitables with `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`.

You can also call nested generators for this example with `yield from` keyword.