# How to convert AsyncIterable to asyncio Task

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, python-collections

I am using Python 3.11.5 with the below code:

```py
import asyncio
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable


# Leave this iterable be, the question is about
# how to use many instances of this in parallel
async def iterable() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3


# How can one get multiple async iterables to work with asyncio.gather?
# In other words, since asyncio.gather works with asyncio.Task,
# (1) How can one convert an async iterable to a Task?
# (2) How can one use asyncio.gather to run many of these tasks in parallel,
#     keeping the results 1-1 with the source iterables?
results_1, results_2, results_3 = asyncio.gather(iterable(), iterable(), iterable())
```

To restate the question, how can one get:

- An `AsyncIterable` as an `asyncio` task, where the task iterates until exhaustion
- Run multiple of these tasks in parallel, storing the results on a per-task basis

(e.g. for use with `asyncio.gather`)?

I am looking for a 1 - 3 line snippet showing how to connect these dots.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what are you trying to achieve? I mean, there's no obvious meaning for awaiting or `asyncio.gather`'ing an async generator - what should this produce? You yield numbers, so it's not about async iterable producing new futures, right? Then what should happen - wait for first item? Consume this generator entirely as `async for` would do?

Comment: @STerliakov I have updated the question, let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: What does "running" a generator mean for you? It can be consumed using `async for item in iterable()` to read the values from it sequentially. You put this async-for loop into an async function and run it in any convenient method (entrypoint - `asyncio.run`).

Comment: Okay, I have expanded the question a bit to make it more clear @STerliakov. `asyncio.run` may be part of the answer. Thanks for asking for clarification!

Comment: I think you are looking for such a manner to have concurrency via `asyncio` for your methods or generators. I suggest check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270147/how-to-write-your-own-async-awaitable-coroutine-function-in-python) out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your code snippet, you're trying to pass an async generator function (iterable) directly to `asyncio.gather`, however, it expects awaitables (coroutines, Tasks, or Futures). So, to fix the issue, one possible solution is, to create a new coroutine that consumes the async `iterable()`s and collects their items in the lists.

The code will be like this:

```py
async def collect(async_iterable):
    return [item async for item in async_iterable]

results = asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(
    asyncio.create_task(collect(iterable())),
    asyncio.create_task(collect(iterable())),
    asyncio.create_task(collect(iterable()))
))
```

In this way, you would have three `[1,2,3]` lists, but still, there is a problem — you haven't gone through a concurrency manner among the `iterable()`s. I mean by adding a `print` within the `collect()` you see they are running sequentially. Therefore, to have an asynchronous behaviour between your iterables you need at least an `await` statement within the generator to make it as an awaitable coroutine used for switching. Here we can use `await asyncio.sleep(0)` as a trick!

Here's the whole code:

```py
import asyncio
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable

async def iterable() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    yield 1
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    yield 2
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    yield 3

async def collect(async_iterable: AsyncIterable[int]) -> list:
    result = []
    async for item in async_iterable:
        print(item)
        result.append(item)
    return result

async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(collect(iterable())),
        asyncio.create_task(collect(iterable())),
        asyncio.create_task(collect(iterable()))
    ]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

results_1, results_2, results_3 = asyncio.run(main())
print(results_1, results_2, results_3)
```

Out:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```